# C# Console Application - Inactivity in a folder

Tags: c#, console-application

I am fairly new to C# coding.. I am trying to setup a code that will alert me when there is an inactivity in a folder. We have a current and archive folder. Once the file is processed in the current folder it will move onto the archive folder.
I have the code to check if there are files in the current folder that's the easy part

```
        DirectoryInfo id = new DirectoryInfo(@"C\");
        FileInfo[] TXTFiles = id.GetFiles("*.txt");
        if (TXTFiles.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Files does not ");
            Console.WriteLine("Checking the last processed file in the Archive directory");
            Console.Read();
        }
        if (TXTFiles.Length != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Files exists ");
            Console.Read();
        }
```

So in the logic where the file does not exist I want to have an additional step to get the timestamp of the last text file that was processed. This is to check for how long there hasnt been any activity .
I am not sure how to proceed. Also instead of writing this information to a console can i send a message to a webservice

Thanks

Comment: You can check the archive folder for the last write to it. You can create a log file where you store each action and a timestamp, the last record is what you what to check. You can use a database or an xml file to store such data. And yes you can sent your debug messages to a webservice, have a look at log4net it has implementation for such functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileSystemWatcher` will be your friend :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Watcher
{

    public static void Main()
    {
    Run();

    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // If a directory is not specified, exit program.
        if(args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

Source code from MSDN.